# broken minicart - urgent

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, javascript, error, mini-cart

I have attempted to edit the minicart on our webstore, however this resulted in an error occurring which seems to be quite common but no one seems to have an easy fix. The minicart now outputs a JS error in the console:

> **type error: unable to bind ko if: getCartParam('summary_count')**

This has been on our website for three days now and it is affecting sales. I am new to magento and messed up by editing the vendor/magento/module-checkout files.

I want to revert back to the vanilla checkout but am struggling with this. Does anyone know where I may find the original files?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the original Magento files for your version in the Magento release archive at https://magento.com/tech-resources/download.

1. Download the right version (zip, tar.gz, or tar.bz2
2. After extracting the downloaded archive you can find the original files in vendor/magento/module-checkout

After you manage to fix your issue it might be worth considering to work with a version control system like git. With such a system in place you can always revert back to an earlier version in case of a mistake or unexpected side effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert everything using composer. Try to remove everything in vendor/magento directory and run `composer install` cli command. Please don't do it on production site directly, first you need to update the code on "staging" instance, then test, then deploy on production environment